# Query that can get player's name if it is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure what to call this but basically, my database has games that can be  played by 1 to 4 players.

The `Games` table has 4 foreign keys to the `PlayerGames` table. GameFirstPlace, GameSecondPlace... etc. They can be null.

If they are not they point to an entry in the `PlayerGames` table.

The `PlayerGames` table has, among other things, a foreign key to the `players` table. The `players` table has PlayerName.

I want to get the PlayerName for all the participants of a Game where PlayerGame is not null.

That is, if my game looks like:

```
GameFirstPlace   GameSecondPlace   GameThirdPlace   GameFourthPlace
     6                   7               NULL            NULL

Then PlayerGame id 6 has PlayerID = 7 and PlayerGame id 7 has PlayerID 3
Then Player with id 7 PlayerName = 'Jack' and Player with id 3 PlayerName = 'Mary'
```

Then my query might return:

```
GameID   FirstPlaceName   SecondPlaceName ThirdPlaceName FourthPlaceName
   5          'Jack'          'Mary'         NULL           NULL
```

What might the select query for something like this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Game.GameID
    ,Player1.Name AS FirstPlaceName
    ,Player2.Name AS SecondPlaceName
    ,Player3.Name AS ThirdPlaceName
    ,Player4.Name AS FourthPlaceName
FROM
    Game
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayerGame as PlayerGame1 ON Game.GameFirstPlace = PlayerGame1.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Player AS Player1 ON PlayerGame1.PlayerId = Player1.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayerGame as PlayerGame2 ON Game.GameSecondPlace = PlayerGame2.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Player AS Player2 ON PlayerGame2.PlayerId = Player2.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayerGame as PlayerGame3 ON Game.GameSecondPlace = PlayerGame3.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Player AS Player3 ON PlayerGame3.PlayerId = Player3.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayerGame as PlayerGame4 ON Game.GameFirstPlace = PlayerGame4.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Player AS Player4 ON PlayerGame4.PlayerId = Player4.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to duplicate all of the join logic four ways.

```
select
    g.GameID,
    p1.PlayerName as FirstPlaceName,
    p2.PlayerName as SecondPlaceName,
    p3.PlayerName as ThirdPlaceName,
    p4.PlayerName as FourthPlaceName
from
    Games g
    left outer join PlayerGames pg1 on pg1.PlayerID = g.GameFirstPlace
    left outer join Players p1 on p1.PlayerID = pg1.PlayerID
    left outer join PlayerGames pg2 on pg2.PlayerID = g.GameSecondPlace
    left outer join Players p2 on p2.PlayerID = pg2.PlayerID
    left outer join PlayerGames pg3 on pg3.PlayerID = g.GameThirdPlace
    left outer join Players p3 on p3.PlayerID = pg3.PlayerID
    left outer join PlayerGames pg4 on pg4.PlayerID = g.GameFourthPlace
    left outer join Players p4 on p4.PlayerID = pg4.PlayerID
```

I'm guessing that your `PlayerGame` table has a `GameID` which you could take advantage of to simplify the join logic. The output gets a little more complicated in return but the query will probably perform better.

```
SELECT
    g.GameID,
    min(case when p.PlayerID = g.GameFirstPlace  then p.PlayerName end) AS FirstPlaceName,
    min(case when p.PlayerID = g.GameSecondPlace then p.PlayerName end) AS SecondPlaceName,
    min(case when p.PlayerID = g.GameThirdPlace  then p.PlayerName end) AS ThirdPlaceName,
    min(case when p.PlayerID = g.GameFourthPlace then p.PlayerName end) AS FourthPlaceName
FROM
    Games g
    inner join PlayerGames pg on pg.GameID = g.GameID
    inner join Players p on p.PlayerID = pg.PlayerID
GROUP BY
    g.GameID
```

Comment: No you need to use LEFT JOIN to handle the empty instances where there is no player.

Comment: I re-read the question and yes there is a lot that's not right.

Comment: Not quite, the Game points to the PlayerGames table, the PlayerGames table points to the Players table... you have the Games table pointing to the Players table...

Comment: I apologize for getting the names mixed up.

Comment: Spend the time writing an answer functionally identical to the one later accepted. Still get downvoted. Loving SO these days.

Comment: I know. You have to wait the downvoter realize you fix your answer. Or just delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT GameID, 
         P1.PlayerName FirstPlaceName,
         P2.PlayerName SecondPlaceName,
         P3.PlayerName ThirdPlaceName,
         P4.PlayerName FourthPlaceName
  FROM Games G
  LEFT JOIN PlayerGames P1
         ON  G.GameFirstPlace  = P1.PlayerID
  LEFT JOIN PlayerGames P2
         ON  G.GameSecondPlace = P2.PlayerID
  LEFT JOIN PlayerGames P3
         ON  G.GameThirdPlace  = P3.PlayerID
  LEFT JOIN PlayerGames P4
         ON  G.GameFourthPlace = P4.PlayerID
```

Comment: Not quite, the Game points to the PlayerGames table, the PlayerGames table points to the Players table... you have the Games table pointing to the Players table...

Comment: mmm let me check. but there is better way of describe schema in a question :P

Comment: Basically you need to join from Games table to PlayerGames table THEN join from PlayerGames table to Players table.

Comment: You dont say what is the field to join FK `PlayerGames` is `ID`?